# Implement Hash Tables separate chaining with vectors

Tags: c++, vector, hashtable

Does anyone know how to add a vector into an array?

I'm given a array table but to solve collisions, i need to implement vectors.

I am provided with this code:

```
void generateTable(string DNA, int N, int K, int *&table) { 
    int tableSize = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
        table[i] = 0;
```

I had planned to implement the hashing as such:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N - K; i++) {
        temp = DNA.substr(i, K);

        for (int j = 0; j < K; j++) {
            value = value * 10 + convert(temp[j]) //this is just to convert the substr into int.
            if (table[value % tableSize] == 0)
                table[value % tableSize] = value;
            else {
                //this is where i plan to use vectors to solve collisions
```

thank you so much for your help. Do let me know if there is any confusion about my question

Comment: It's not clear at all how using vectors would help in solving collisions.

Comment: @molbdnilo i think OP wants to have an array of vectors instead of an array of linked list to solve collisions

Comment: @GauravSehgal The given table is an array of `int`, not of linked lists. AFAIK, the way to solve collisions in that case is through open addressing.

Comment: that is correct @GauravSehgal. i need to use vectors instead of linked list

Comment: @brandnewprogrammer Then you need your table to be an array of vectors, not an array of integers.

Comment: @molbdnilo im not able to change it to vectors though... i was wondering if there is a way to add vectors to an individual array. for example, when there is a collision at array[1], i can link an vector to it and can push_back the value

Comment: If your hashtable is an array of `int`s, you can't use a linked list either. At least one piece of the puzzle is missing for anyone to be able to provide you with any advice.

Comment: Side note: the `int *&table` parameter is odd - if you're expected to resize the table, you also need a way of communicating its new size. If you're not expected to resize the table, the reference doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @molbdnilo those were all in the skeleton code so we have to work with it hahaha

Comment: @molbdnilo do you think it is possible to `vector<int> hash_table` to convert table to vector?

Comment: @brandnewprogrammer You can't do separate chaining at all if your hash table is an array of `int`. Either you or your teacher must have missed some detail somewhere.